# C - generic function: swap two items in array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers, generic-programming

My problem: **I would like to create function that can swap any two items in array of generic type.**

I have SwapG function that can swap two items of any type:

```
void SwapG(void * a, void * b, size_t size)
{
    void * temp = malloc(size);
    memcpy(temp, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, temp, size);
}
```

Here is my attempt of function that would swap two items in array of any type:

```
void SwapInArrayG(void ** arr, int a, int b, size_t size)
{
    void * temp = malloc(size);
    memcpy(temp, *(arr + a), size);
    memcpy(*(arr + a), *(arr + b), size);
    memcpy(*(arr + b), temp, size);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I messed the pointers up, still I can't find solution. I would appreciate any help :).

Comment: Note: after the copy is done, good to `free(temp);`

Comment: What's the problem using a simple macro? Your code is an invitation to programming errors and will be very slow allocating/freeing memory for each swap

Comment: If you want to swap two entries in the same array, why don't you use the first function? `SwapG(&array[idx1], &array[idx2], sizeof(entry))`

Comment: @EOF Your code will swap the addresses of the pointers not the data that the pointers point to.

Comment: @JoelTrauger: No. The call will *pass* the pointers to the objects to the `SwapG()`-function, which uses `memcpy()` on those pointers.

Comment: @EOF I mixed up which set of code you were referencing. My bad.

Comment: You need to show how you're calling `SwapInArrayG`. `void **` is suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to a `void *` is not defined.  Cast to `char *`.

Possibly need to need to de-reference `arr`, but I think OP's signature should be adjusted instead.  See [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932526/c-generic-function-swap-two-items-in-array/37932664?noredirect=1#comment63316041_37932526)

Scale the pointer calculation [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932526/c-generic-function-swap-two-items-in-array/37932664#comment63315946_37932664)

Free the allocated memory too.

---

I'd expect passing a `void *` to be sufficient.

```
void SwapInArrayG(void * arr, int a, int b, size_t size) {
    void * temp = malloc(size);
    if (size > 0) {
      assert(temp);
      assert(a >= 0 && b >= 0);
      memcpy(temp, (char *)arr + size*a, size);
      memcpy((char *)arr + size*a, (char *)arr + size*b, size);
      memcpy((char *)arr + size*b, temp, size);
    }
    free(temp);  
}
```

Unclear on how OP calls this function, but the following is typical.

```
foo_type G[some_size];
SwapInArrayG(G, index_a, index_b, sizeof *G);
```

Note: depending on coding goals, using indexes of type `size_t` is usually preferred over type `int`.

Note: that `assert(temp);` is within `if (size > 0)` as allocating 0 bytes may return `NULL` and *not* be out-of-memory.  OTOH, `size == 0` is most unusual.

Comment: @chox Thanks a lot, sorry if this question was dumb, I'm just learning C